# DPDK: TX checksum offload for IP fragmented on AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, dpdk

I've noticed that TX checksumming offload for IP fragments is not working
in ES2 instance C5 with latest DPDK 17.11 (ENA driver). For not fragmented
IP traffic the offload works well.

The same code is working on ES2 instance M4 with DPDK 16.08 (AFAIR ixgbe_vf
driver).

The code does the following:

- sets mbuf *ol_flags* to *PKT_TX_IPV4* | *PKT_TX_IP_CKSUM*
- sets mbuf *l2_len* to ethernet header len
- sets mbuf *l3_len* to IP header len

Any ideas?

Comment: "not working" meaning data corruption/failures? Logged messages? Can't be enabled?  Slow? Or something else?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Good point. I actually don't know.
I know that packets are dropped, so checksum is not calculated in HW at all or calculated incorrectly.

Comment: Try to play with TSO, i.e. turn it on/off. There were bugs in ENA firmware re TSO and checksums.

Comment: @AndriyBerestovskyy Thanks!! I definitely try. Do you have some reference to the issue?

Comment: @dimba Not sure if there is anything else publicly available but [this troubleshooting guide.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting-ena.html) And here is the DPDK commit mentioning TSO, checksums and firmware bug: http://git.dpdk.org/dpdk/commit/?id=bc5ef57d43c5f4ea423734b2aeae070ae19dd91f

Comment: Overall, there are lots of changes in DPDK 18.05, so it might also make sense to test that version...